# PHP/MYSQL: Pulling information from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have done a little bit of research on this, but currently I'm stuck.

My situation:

My database has a serverName, and serverBanner for each entry.  When I do this following code:

```
function listBanner() {

include("mysql.php"); 

$votes = "serverVotes";
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM toplist ORDER BY $votes ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    echo "&nbsp; " . "<img src=" . $row['serverBanner'] . " height=60 width=460 />";

}
}
```

If you noticed, it is pulling all the info from toplist table.  I need to pull all the info from toplist table, but make it so that I can put each on if them in a table row.  Right now if I did that, it would put each banner in the same table row.

Also, how would I go about implementing this into a table?

Comment: you could place your table row inside while and loop thru..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
<?php
    echo "<tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        echo "<td>" . $row['serverName'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" . "<img src=" . $row['serverBanner'] . " height=60 width=460 />"."</td>";    
    }
    echo "</tr>"

?>
```

Comment: its the detailed answer.. isnt it...?

Comment: These are close, but any idea how to make it so that One column is the name, one column is banner, etc?

Comment: @user1218844 Yeah but in the same row, it will be weird for the eyes ;) You will have a name, then a banner, then a name, then a banner, etc...!

Comment: see edited code, you could add td having name and other td having serverbanner as in code..

Comment: Its all in the same column now.  I cant get them in 2 separate columns.

Comment: should have been in in two separate td's the servername and serverbanner as per the code... or do you mean something else...?